# Pandas fill nan with values from another column with conditional?

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, fillna

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'feature1_in_use?': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     'feature1_available?': [0, 1, 1, 'NA', 1, 'NA', 1, 1, 'NA', 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In the column 'feature1_available?' I want to fill the nan with the values from 'feature1_in_use?   ' only when these are 1, otherwise fill it up with 'X' or any valid string.

It should look like this:

```
data = {'feature1_in_use?': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     'feature1_available?': [0, 1, 1, 'X', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexible option you could use would be `np.select()`

```
data = {'feature1_in_use?': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     'feature1_available?': [0, 1, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['feature1_available?'] = df['feature1_available?'].replace({np.nan : None})
condition_list = [
    ((df['feature1_available?'].values == None) & (df['feature1_in_use?'] == 1)),
    ((df['feature1_available?'].values == None) & (df['feature1_in_use?'] == 0))
]
choice_list = [df['feature1_in_use?'], 'X']
df['feature1_available?'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, df['feature1_available?'])
df
```

Comment: This one works really well in the example df. However, it returns an error in my original df.
"TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray". It points to the application of np.select(). Can you explained why is this the case?

Comment: I’m not sure, it’s got to be something about your data (I’m guessing) is it possible to get a larger data set?

Comment: My mistake. My df represents NaN as <NA> and the dtype is Int64. I am looking how to correctly manipulate this. But if you know how, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I've updated my code to resolve np.nan's in the data

Comment: Hi, I am sorry this thing keeps breaking my notebook. I am pretty sure it has to do with the <NA> type and the I (capital i) Int64 dtype. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dxxo2lwgs0xbs3q/AACl00EciazHiKt54aiqD365a?dl=0 let me know if you can access this dataset? However, it might come with "typical" NaN rather than <NA>. I found this discussion but I don't quite understand. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25288  I tried changing the dtypes but nothing works. In a real case scenario I think I'd do that step in Excel to continue with my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want your blank value to be 'x' then do the following:

```
df['feature1_available'] = df['feature1_available'].fillna(df['feature1_in_use'])

df['feature1_in_use'] = df['feature1_in_use'].fillna('x')
```

Step 1 fills blank values in **feature1_available** from **feature1_in_use**. Step 2 fills any remaining nan values with 'x' (or any other value you choose

Answer (score 0):

The first line creates a series where everything other than 1 is 'X'. Then 'NA' is replaced with `np.NaN` which allows us to fill in the missing values with the series that was created

```
s = df['feature1_in_use?'].where(df['feature1_in_use?'].eq(1),'X')
df.replace('NA',np.NaN).fillna({'feature1_available?':s})
```

Output:

```
    feature1_in_use? feature1_available?
0                  0                 0.0
1                  0                 1.0
2                  1                 1.0
3                  0                   X
4                  1                 1.0
5                  1                   1
6                  1                 1.0
7                  0                 1.0
8                  1                   1
9                  0                 1.0
10                 1                 1.0
```